# How can you longpoll multiple urls in Go?

Tags: go, long-polling

Here's what I have thus far:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func subscribe(urls Urls) []byte {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", urls.Url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("authentication", "Bearer " + urls.Token)

    http_client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := http_client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    resourceResp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(resourceResp))

    var data map[string]interface{}

    error := json.Unmarshal([]byte(resourceResp), &data)
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
    }

    return subscribe(urls)
}

type Urls struct {
    Url string
    Token string
}

func main() {
    var urls [2]Urls

    urls[0] = Urls{
        Url: "https://example.com/users/8",
        Token: "abcdefg",
    }

    urls[1] = Urls{
        Url:   "https://example.com/users/9",
        Token: "hijklmnop",
    }

    subscribe(urls[0])
    subscribe(urls[1])
}
```

The end goal is to "subscribe" to the multiple urls and pull any updated data (eventually adding it to a queue, but one step at a time). After that, reestablish the connection.  Right now, only the first subscribe gets run.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're asking is for the `subscribe` functions to be run in parallel. One way is to wrap them in *goroutines* and wait for all the *goroutines* to finish:

```
func main() {
    ...
    ...
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(len(urls))

    for _, url := range(urls) {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            subscribe(url)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! I'm new-ish to Go, so I have a couple of questions. Cuould this be done in a loop, so if I have 20 urls I wouldn't need to hardcode the goroutine? Also, how do think this would scale, to something like 10 thousand users? Thanks again!

Comment: Updated the answer to use a loop. In terms of scaling - subscribe() calls itself recursively and to the best of my knowledge Go doesn't implement tail call optimization so you would run out of memory fairly quickly with the code as it stands. Alternative techniques like task queues + scheduler or a technology that supports push (e.g. websockets) would scale better than long polling.

Comment: For some reason, if I just pass the `url` to the subscribe function, it would only trigger the 2nd element in the array. When I set a new variable `newUrl := url` and used THAT in function, it worked.  Unfortunately, I'm not in control of the url that's sending the information, so I'm stuck with longpolling (or something similar). Thanks again!

Comment: Ooops, sorry - fixed a typo: should have been `subscribe(url)` not `subscribe(urls[0])`